# filtering a fulltext search with a relationship constraint

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently trying to filter the nodes retrieved from a fulltext search based on an existing relationship.

Here's the code (please note the 'note sure how to properly filter' line

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(
    "titleAndKeywords", 
    $search_text) 
YIELD node
WITH node
    WHERE $label in labels(node)
OPTIONAL MATCH // <-- not sure how to properly filter
    (a:Account {
            id : $account_id
        })
    -[:MEMBER]->
    (node)
    WHERE a IS NOT null
WITH
    node,
    COLLECT(node) AS nodes,
    COUNT(node) AS total
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (node)
    WHERE
        node.account_id = $account_id
WITH
    nodes + COLLECT(node) AS n,
    total + COUNT(node) AS total
UNWIND n AS node
WITH
    node,
    total
        SKIP $skip
        LIMIT $limit
WITH
    COLLECT(node) AS results,
    total
RETURN results, total
```

So, from the code, for the first OPTIONAL MATCH, I am trying to get only the nodes which have a MEMBER relationship. However, what this full query does is return me duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but there are some red flags in your query I would like to point out.

```
WITH
    node,
    COLLECT(node) AS nodes,
    COUNT(node) AS total
```

When aggregating with the cypher, it uses an implied grouping, meaning that all the columns in the `WITH` statement are automatically used to aggregate by or a groupby of the SQL world. So your the above statement will always collect only 1 node and the count will be 1 as well.

Next, you already have a node variable declared, yet you use it in the `OPTIONAL MATCH`, which is weird and probably wrong.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (node)
    WHERE
        node.account_id = $account_id
```

This is probably also the place where you create more duplicates.

If you only want to filter out the nodes that have a MEMBER relationship to the specific account id, I would use the following query:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(
    "titleAndKeywords", 
    $search_text) 
YIELD node
WITH node
    WHERE $label in labels(node)
// Filter our only nodes with a relationship
// to specific account
MATCH 
    (a:Account {
            id : $account_id
        })
    -[:MEMBER]->
    (node)
// collect the nodes so we can get the total
WITH collect(nodes) as nodes, 
     count(*) as total
// You can do the pagination as array slicing
RETURN nodes[$skip..$skip + $limit] as result, total
```

Comment: I'm currently working on it. I realized that I could do something like `node = another_node`, and they will match up perfectly (basically like an inner join). But I will give your queries a try. So the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` is trying to only find nodes that have the matching `account_id` on it.

Comment: I have found a query that does what I want. Please check it out and let me know if you think anything could be improved

Answer (score 1):

Did you try, instead of OPTIONAL MATCH

WHERE
(a:Account {
id : $account_id
})
-[:MEMBER]->
(node))

Comment: didn't realize you could do that. I will try something like that if my future queries have that sort of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with in the end, using node matching

```
CALL {
    MATCH 
        (a:Account { 
                id : $account_id 
            })
        -[:MEMBER]->
        (n1:Workspace)
    RETURN n1 AS n
    
    UNION
    
    MATCH
        (n2:Workspace { 
            account_id : $account_id
        })
    RETURN n2 AS n
}

CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(
    "titleAndKeywords", 
    $search_text) 
YIELD node

WITH n, node
    WHERE n = node

WITH
    COLLECT(n) AS results,
    COUNT(n) AS total
    
RETURN results[$skip..$skip + $limit] AS results, total
```

Comment: If you have a guarantee that first part of the query before the FT search will always return only a single node, then it's fine. If that guarantee doesn't exist you can use "n in node"

Comment: @TomažBratanič I get an error when I use "IN". I think that's because `node` isn't a list. Seems to work fine with `=`